# Why is the exe I made using pyinstaller requiring administrator login?

Tags: python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I made an exe with pyinstaller but it requires an administrator login whenever it is run. I checked the manifest file and it matches the name of the executable. I have made executable files from py files before without the executables requiring administrator login so I am not sure what is going wrong.

I searched stackoverflow to see if anyone had a similar problem but all the solutions I found pointed to the manifest file's name being different from the executable's name which is not the problem in my case.

If it helps, I am using -F for onefile. Also, according to the window asking for administrator permission whenever the exe is run, administrator login is required because the exe has an unknown publisher.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it this will solve your issue.
Few months ago, I was looking for the same thing and it came up that I need a real certificate. Never done it.

[Trusted Publishers Certificate Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/trusted-publishers-certificate-store)

> The Trusted Publishers certificate store contains information about
>   the Authenticode (signing) certificates of trusted publishers that are
>   installed on a computer. In order to test and debug your driver
>   packages within your organization, your company should install the
>   Authenticode certificates that are used to sign driver packages in the
>   Trusted Publishers certificate store. Install the Authenticode
>   certificates on each computer in the workgroup or organizational unit
>   that runs signed code. The name of the Trusted Publishers certificate
>   store is trustedpublisher.

Comment: Just tell me if it's useful. If not, then I just misunderstood your issue.

Comment: It seems weird that my earlier exe's did not have the same problem as this one. In either case, I hope there is another solution since I doubt I can convince my employer to purchase a certificate so I am honestly not sure if I can test whether this is the cause of my problem.

Comment: No idea, sorry. Actually, I never published a released version of my programs as .exe.